# Blurred text using transform-style in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have problem with CSS below. In div with class `front` text is blurred like on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USncd.jpg)

I'm using Chrome, but on every browser I see same blurred text. I want keep every div but I'm not sure what makes this text so blurred.

**How I can fix it to make it no blure?**

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmbou9Lw/)

**HTML and CSS**

```css
.main {
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.panel {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 14px;
}

.est {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.flip .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

#card-1,
#card-2,
#card-3,
#card-4,
#card-5 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  perspective: 700px;
}

h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.35;
  color: #222;
  background: #f4f5f7;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 1;
}

.back,
.front {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back,
.front,
.front .info-box,
.social-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.ease {
  -webkit-transition: all .45s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .45s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .45s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .45s ease-out;
  transition: all .45s ease-out;
}

.e-i-f-about,
.front,
.p-class-earn,
.strike {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.back,
.flip .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back,
.front {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back,
.front,
.front .info-box,
.social-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.back {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: table;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 23px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main pad-2">
  <center>
    <h4>Not blurred text</h4>
    <div class="panel e-b est" style="margin-top:0">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="card-1">
          <div class="front ease">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open-1" id="open-1">Click</a>
            <div class="info-box">
              <div class="info">
                <h4>test1 blurred text</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back ease">
            2nd text here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel e-b est" style="margin-top:0">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="card-2">
          <div class="front ease">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open-2" id="open-2">Click</a>
            <div class="info-box">
              <div class="info">
                <h4>test2 blurred text</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back ease">
            2nd text here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you think about overlap this `div` with a `div:after ` blurred?

Comment: Try removing the back class? I am not sure what you mean, because it you want no blur, but your code makes a blur, like you want it.

Comment: Using the code that you have provided, I am unable to reproduce what you have demonstrated in the provided image. Please update your question to include all of the relevant code.

Comment: @KonradStrek it is your `transform: rotateY(180deg)` but you need this to be able to flip the animation (if that's what you're doing?). What are you actually trying to achieve with the whole thing? There may be an alternative way of doing it.

Comment: I came to a slightly different conclusion than @coops, but it is definitely a known issue with the rendering. Removing `perspective: 700px;` from your `#card-1` does fix this issue but breaks your layout. As @coops has mentioned, there may be another way for you to handle this.

Comment: @coops Here is my exactly code from website. Most important for me is to get same animation on click. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tmbou9Lw/1/)

Comment: @coops Try again, make sure you have JQuery included for this animation.

Comment: I've searched around and cannot seem to find a reliable solution. I've upvoted your question - hopefully we can spread awareness and someone can provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, I also have searched and found that where I have used this flip animation, the `.front` has always contained an image - so I have never noticed any text being blurry. This could possibly be an option for you? I have upvoted as well.

Comment: @coops Even if it contains image, the text below or above the block in front or black is always blurred :/

Comment: @coops But this problem is visible from 1-2 months, because before on Chrome everything was fine.

Comment: No answer yet? Unfortunate. =|